# How to split a string and store each character into an array

Tags: c, arrays

I'm trying to compare the number of similar characters between 2 string and came across strpbrk() function. But I can't find any method to split my search string into array of character.

```
char search[] = "chzi";
char arr[2][20] = {"cheang", "wai"};
float lengthSearch = strlen(search);
float count = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
    int lengthArr = strlen(arr[i]);

    for(int j = 0; j < lengthSearch; j++){
      if(strpbrk(&search[j], arr[i])){
        printf("%c is the similarity between %s and %s\n", *strpbrk(&search[j], arr[i]), &search[j], arr[i]);

        count++;
        printf("count is now %.1f\n", count);
      }
    }

    float probability = ((count/lengthSearch) * (count/lengthArr)) * 100;

    printf("%s has a probability of %.2f\n\n", arr[i], probability);
    count = 0;
  }
```

The problem is here

```
i is the similarity between chzi and wai
count is now 1.0
i is the similarity between hzi and wai
count is now 2.0
i is the similarity between zi and wai
count is now 3.0
i is the similarity between i and wai
count is now 4.0
```

instead of chzi I only want to compare c and wai

Comment: Your `search` string is already an array of characters and you can iterate over each character with a simple `for (int i = 0; search[i]; i++)` where `search[i]` will be each character in `search` in sequence. `if(strpbrk(&search[j], arr[i]))` is backwards. If you want to know if any of the chars in `search` appear in `arr[i]` then `strpbrk (arr[i], search)`

Comment: `float` is wrong, `size_t` it the return type for `strlen`. See [`man 3 strlen`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strlen.3.html)

Comment: looping through the string will return me each character but when using strpbrk(), it forces me to write in ```strpbrk(&seach[j], arr[i])```, if i am able to just write ```strpbrk(search[j], arr[i])``` I believe this code should be good

Comment: strpbrk doesn't work the way you think it works, read the documentation carefully.

Comment: I want to check if the first character of search matches any character in the string, that's why I wrote ```strpbrk(&search[j], arr[i])```

Comment: Do you only what to know if the first character matches, or do you want to know the number of occurrences of characters in `search` that are contained in `arr[i]`??

Comment: "I want to check if the first character of search matches any character in the string," That's not what strpbrk does.

Comment: I wanted to check how many similar characters between ```search``` and ```arr[i]```

Comment: No - `strpbrk` returns a pointer to the first of any character in `search` that matches. Use `strchr (arr[i], search[0])` to find out if the first char in `search` matches any char in `arr[i]`.

Comment: OH -- that's what I thought, then you can use `strpbrk` and a pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I wanted to check how many similar characters between `search` and
>   `arr[i]`

Then you can use `strpbrk` but somewhat reversed from how you attempted. [`man 3 strpbrk`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strpbrk.3.html) with declaration of

> ```
> char *strpbrk(const char *s, const char *accept);
>
> locates the first occurrence in the string s
> of any of the bytes in the string accept.
> ```

So what you want do is simply loop with `strpbrk` and find out how many characters of `search` are common to `arr[i]`. Using a pointer makes that simple, e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void) {

    char search[] = "chzi",
        arr[][20] = {"cheang", "wai"};
    size_t n = sizeof arr / sizeof *arr;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        size_t count = 0;
        char *p = arr[i];
        while ((p = strpbrk (p, search)))
            count++, p++;
        printf ("%s contains %zu occurrence of characters in %s.\n",
                arr[i], count, search);
    }
}
```

Note above you simply use a pointer to `arr[i]` and then use `strpbrk` to locate the first character in `search` that occurs in `arr[i]`. You then increment the pointer to the next character in `arr[i]` (using `p++;`) and do it again until `strpbrk` returns `NULL` indicating there are no more character is `arr[i]` that match any of the characters in `search`, the code above does just this, e.g.

```
        char *p = arr[i];
        while ((p = strpbrk (p, search)))
            count++, p++;
```

which if you wanted to avoid using the comma operator would be:

```
        char *p = arr[i];
        while ((p = strpbrk (p, search))) {
            count++;
            p++;
        }
```

**Example Use/Output**

Running with your strings would result in:

```
$ ./bin/strpbrkchars
cheang contains 2 occurrence of characters in chzi.
wai contains 1 occurrence of characters in chzi.
```

Look things over and let me know if that is what you intended. You will need to add your probability code, but that is left to you.

Comment: What does this do? ```p = strpbrk (p, search)``` Does it means that if the first character of ```p``` matches any character in ```search``` it will return that character and store it in ```p```?

Comment: Recall, `strpbrk` returns a pointer to the first character in `p` (`arr[i]`) that matches any of the characters in `search`. So in the case of `cheang`, `strpbrk` will return a pointer to `c` at the beginning. You then increment `count++` and `p++` so `p` now points to `h` and you loop again. `h` matches so `strpbrk` returns a pointer to `h` on the second iteration. You then `count++;` and `p++;` so `p` now points to `e`. On your next call, nothing in `"eang"` matches any character in `"chzi"`, so `strpbrk` returns `NULL` completing the loop.

Comment: Add a new string `"caching"` to your array and you will find `count == 4` as it matches `c` (2-times), `h` (1-time) and `i` (1-time).